# why I got an exception complaining that I have a null value of the attribute (which is not as I printed out in code)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a code for updating a db table record - load the entity from the db and then set attribute A and save it back to the db (attrB should stay the same value as before). However, I keep getting an exception as below:

`ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=attrB, rootBeanClass=class ......`

Below is my entity file and code

Entity file:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "myEntity")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BaseMyEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @NotNull
    private String attrA;

    @NotNull
    private UUID attrC;

    ......
}
```

and base entity file is

```
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    protected UUID attrB;

    ......
}
```

And the update code is

```
    @Transactional
    public boolean updateAttrB(UUID attrBValue) {
        Optional<T> entityOptional = getRepository().findById(id);
        T entity = entityOptional.get();
        entity.setAttrA(attrBValue);  // change A's value, keep B same
        System.out.printlin("attrB: " + entity.getAttrB());  // print out and see
        
        save(entity);

        return true;
    }

    protected T save(T entity) {
        return getRepository().saveAndFlush(entity);
    }
```

As you can see from the code, I try to see the attrB value. It did has an UUID value printed out, which is the value existed in the db.

Moreover, please note the attrB field in the entity file should corresponds to a column called attr_b in the table. The code was there from day one. It is still mystery for me to find out how does attr_b map to attrB without specify any annotation. Not sure if it is related. But thought worth to mention.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring is not JPA, and will change the naming formats used by Hibernate by default so that camel case gets translated to snake format - there are numerous questions on it, but what works for JPA (which would default to a column 'ATTRB' or 'attrb' because dbs are generally case insensitive, works to be 'attr_b' in spring.  In your code, what is the "attrBValue" that you are passing to the setAttrB method? You are printing the existing DB attrB value, but not the one you are setting it to - could it be null?

Comment: @Chris, thanks for answering the name convention concern. For the printing value, I didn't have a new value for it. As you can see, I load the entity from db and only update the attrA (not attrB) and then want to save it back to db. To summarize, only the attrA's value needs to be changed. I expect the rest column value stay the same.

Comment: It will be something you haven't shown, as what you've outlined as happening isn't normal for what you have. What is your save method doing exactly? Does this happen for all instances or just on this field in one entity in one situation?

Comment: The save method is being used by some other callers, I believe. I also edit my post including the save() method.

Comment: @Chris, you are right. Some folks recently added PrePersist and PreUpdate in the Entity file, which overwrites the attrB. Please make your comment to be an answer. I will accept it. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was found. Some other folks recently added @preUpdate and @prePersist methods in the Entity file, which overwrites attrB.